# Positioning header-element aligned with wordpress sidebar

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position

I am currently developing the following WordPress page: http://verein-iks.eu/dev/

On the top right corner I have a div containing a few buttons. I would like to have this div aligned with the right sidebar as indicated in this screenshot:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to set a max-width: 1040px for the header element which will be equal to the below content.

Comment: this affects my whole layout, since it changes the width of the whole page to 1040px which is not suitable for me. is there a way without having to set max-width to 1040?

Comment: It actually renders like this: http://prntscr.com/92aleg

Comment: You should really fix the entire layout. You're absolutely positioning things. Whole thing will be a nightmare to fix on mobile. Use bootstrap or similar grid system...

Comment: this is the default twentythirteen theme from wordpress. it already adapts nicely to mobile. i only need to get this thing fixed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another div around `#fb-link`, and give that div:

```
max-width: 1040px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Then remove absolute positioning from `#fb-link`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This one probably should work, inspired by Manoj Kumar. Yeah, and you should move your div back to the original placement.

Comment: You should move your #fb-link div back to where it originally was.

Comment: ok. but now it's on the far right, and not aligned with the sidebar (see screenshot above): http://verein-iks.eu/dev/

Comment: nice. works like a charm now. if you have time, it would be awesome, if you could explain to me, why this works :) thanks again!

Comment: No problem.  :)  Sure, the width is now set to the same max as the element you wanted to align with, and your #fb-link floats to the right within that space. Using margin: auto for the left and right margins, makes sure the remaining space is split equally between left and right margins, again the same way the below element is positioned. Border-box might not be necessary, but adjust what's regarded as width/height, and what as border/padding.

Comment: awesome. perfectly makes sense. so the idea, obviously, is to replicate the css of the below element (and its parent element): a) same margin (`margin: 0 auto`) and same max-width (`max-width: 1040px`). and the child must `float: right`.